# Android AWS DynamoDBMappingException: Null or empty value for key

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying the AWS and got the error after calling identityManager.getCachedUserID():

DynamoDBMappingException: Null or empty value for key: public java.lang.String ***.NewsDO.getUserId().

I'm using the default example News database and can't understand where is the problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
IdentityManager identityManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), // Context
            "here is my pool", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1 // Region
    );

    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute();


    AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
    this.dynamoDBMapper = DynamoDBMapper.builder()
            .dynamoDBClient(dynamoDBClient)
            .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
            .build();

    identityManager = new IdentityManager(getApplicationContext(), new AWSConfiguration(getApplicationContext()));
    IdentityManager.setDefaultIdentityManager(identityManager);

    createNews();
}

public void createNews() {
    final NewsDO newsItem = new NewsDO();

    newsItem.setUserId(identityManager.getCachedUserID());

    newsItem.setArticleId("Article1");
    newsItem.setContent("This is the article content");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dynamoDBMapper.save(newsItem);
            // Item saved
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

With `AWSMobileClient`, when you invoke the initialize method, you have to add a callback object that overrides the `onComplete` method. The `AWSMobileClient` creates the `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider`, `AWSConfiguration` object and `IdentityManager` object based on the `awsconfiguration.json` file. The only caveat is that you have to wait till the `onComplete` method is called for all the initialization to take place. Once the `onComplete` is called, now you can safely retrieve the information you need.

Since `IdentityManager` is a singleton and `AWSMobileClient` internally creates and sets it, you can just invoke I`dentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().getCachedUserID()` to retrieve the identity ID.

I have modified the code to make it work with `AWSMobileClient`.

```
String identityId = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, new AWSStartupHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(AWSStartupResult awsStartupResult) {
                IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().getUserID(new IdentityHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onIdentityId(String s) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                        identityId = s;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleError(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).execute();
    }

    public void createNews() {
        final NewsDO newsItem = new NewsDO();

        newsItem.setUserId(identityId);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I still have the same problem. When I check the "identityManager.getCachedUserID()" it returns Null

Comment: Try getUserId. That should work. I have modified the answer, Please check

Answer (score 0):

This error message can be caused caused by re-initializing the AWSMobileClient in the onCreate method of your second activity as per the AWS example for a NoSQL Database given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html):

Check that if you haven't already created an instance of `AWSMobileClient` in any first sign-in activity, for example.